# Handshake probability problem: Probability that two people shake hands?

Tags: probability

There are groups $A$ and $B$ which have $X$ and $Y$ number of people respectively. They are seated around a round table. Each person can only shake hands with those in their group and only with people on their left and right. Consider person 1 and person 2 from group $A$. What is the probability that they shook hands?

If we fix person 1 to be in the $i$-th seat. Then person 2 has a probability of $\frac{2}{X-1+Y}$ of being in the $(i-1)$-th or $(i+1)$-th seat. This seems to be the probability I get from Monte Carlo.

However, I am confused why this derivation is valid. It is constraining person 1 to be at the $i$-th seat. There are $X+Y$ other seats he could be in, so shouldn't those cases be factored in to the probability somehow?

Another way to phrase my concern is, didn't I find the conditional probability that person 1 and 2 shake hands given that person 1 is seated in the $i$-th seat? In my monte carlo simulation I did not fix the first person to be at some $i$-th seat. I simply looked at all possible cases, but it seems to give me the same answer, so I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

The table is round, and this symmetry causes the dependence of the probability on $i$ to disappear.

No matter where person $1$ is seated, the table can be rotated so that that person occupies any given seat, say seat $1$.

Comment: I think I just realized something and correct me if I'm wrong. In this case it seems the probability is the same as the conditional probability because of the symmetry condition. Specifically

\begin{align}
    P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{X+Y} P(A|s_i) p(s_i) \\
    = (X+Y) * P(A|s_i) \frac{1}{X+Y} = P(A|S_i)
\end{align}

where $A$ is the event that person 1 and 2 meet and $s_i$ is the event that person 1 sits in the $i$-th seat.

Comment: @student10101 Just accept my answer, will you? You can use your own method, and you'll get the same result.